# Behavior of `get` when overriding a method with `with-redefs`

Tags: clojure

I'm writing some unit tests and to do so I'm mocking out some methods. My function looks like:

```
(def my_map {:a 10 :b 20 :c 30})

(defn my-fn []
   (<= (get my_map :a) (get my_map :b)))
```

And I'm mocking out as the following:

```
(with-redefs [my_ns/my_map (fn [] {:a 100 :b 200 :c 300})]
  #(is (= true (my-fn))) ;; other asserts using the overridden function
 )
```

I've realized the statement `(get my_map :a)` is throwing a `NullPointerException` when using the mocked method. However, when executed the same using the original implementation (without mocking) it works fine.

So I realized that if I change to `(get (my_map) :a)` it works fine with mocks but breaks the original implementation.

What am I missing here? I was expecting that `with-redefs` only overrides the implementation of a specific method.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and real code (no double {{...}} stuff).

Comment: If you `def` the map, it is just that, but your redef is basically a `defn` (ignoring the fact, that maps themself are functions)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm entirely understanding what you are trying to achieve, but if what you mean is to call `my-fn` in the context of a modified `my_map`, then you could try

```
(with-redefs [my_map {:a 100 :b 200 :c 300}]
  (= true (my-fn)))
```

This expression temporarily modifies `my_map` and then runs `my-fn` in this new, temporary context. Its value will be the result of `my-fn` with the modified `my_map`.

As as side note, you can use the shorter `(:a my_map)` instead of `(get my_map :a)` (look at what are keywords). Also, since `my-fn` returns a boolean value, instead of `(= true (my-fn))` you could simply use `(my-fn)`.